# Multiple ForegroundColorSpan on Editable issue on Android 6.0+

Tags: android, android-edittext, syntax-highlighting, android-6.0-marshmallow

If I set multiple spans on an `Editable`, the last `ForegroundColorSpan` is used. This is, in my opinion, the expected behavior. On Android 6.0+ the latest set span does not take precedence.

---

Below is a full working example that highlights numbers and then strings in an `EditText`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the EditText view
    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    editText.setBackground(null);
    editText.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);

    // Patterns to find numbers and strings
    final Pattern[] patterns = {
        Pattern.compile("\\b(\\d*[.]?\\d+)\\b"), // numbers
        Pattern.compile("\".*?\"|'.*?'"), // strings
    };

    // Colors for numbers and strings
    final int[] colors = {
        Color.RED,
        Color.BLUE
    };

    // Add a TextWatcher to highlight numbers and strings
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

      }

      @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        // remove all spans before highlighting new text
        ForegroundColorSpan[] spans = editable.getSpans(0, editable.length(), ForegroundColorSpan.class);
        for (ForegroundColorSpan span : spans) {
          editable.removeSpan(span);
        }

        // first, highlight numbers, next strings
        for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
          Pattern p = patterns[i];
          Matcher m = p.matcher(editable);
          while (m.find()) {
            editable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colors[i]), m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            // print match
            System.out.println(editable.subSequence(m.start(), m.end()));
          }
        }

        // PROBLEM:
        // On Android 6.0+ numbers are highlighted within the string.
        // This is not expected behavior. It worked prior to Android 6.0
      }
    });

    // set some text for testing purposes
    editText.setText("foo \"bar\" baz \"quz 16\"");

    setContentView(editText);
  }

}
```

---

If I launch this `Activity` and enter the text

> foo "bar" baz "qux 16"

I would expect "bar" and "qux 16" to both be blue. However, on Android 6.0+ `16` is red.

---

### Here are screenshots:

**Android 5.1.1 (expected behavior)**

[image: Android 5.1.1]

**Android 6.0.1**

[image: Android 6.0.1]

Notice how `16` is highlighted in the second screenshot.

---

### Question:

Why is the first color span overriding the last color span on Android 6.0 and how can I fix this behavior?

Comment: Could you check if what the matcher is returning is what you are expecting ?

Comment: @Blackbelt I just updated the code. It now prints the output of each match. Yes, the output is what I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remove all spans before setting the new `ForegroundColorSpan` then I get the desired behavior. Unfortunately, this is a lot more work if an `EditText` has a lot of text.

What I did for a fix:

```
@Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    // remove old spans before highlighting
    // this does not work on Android 6.0+
    ForegroundColorSpan[] spans = editable.getSpans(0, editable.length(), ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    for (ForegroundColorSpan span : spans) {
      editable.removeSpan(span);
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
    Pattern p = patterns[i];
    Matcher m = p.matcher(editable);
    while (m.find()) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        // Remove any spans in the given range.
        ForegroundColorSpan[] oldspans = editable.getSpans(m.start(), m.end(), ForegroundColorSpan.class);
        for (ForegroundColorSpan span : oldspans) {
          editable.removeSpan(span);
        }
      }
      editable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(colors[i]), m.start(), m.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what changed in Android 6.0+ and if anyone has any insight it would be much appreciated.